# Why is there no "non-empty list" type in the Haskell base libraries?

Tags: list, haskell, types, strong-typing

This type could be

```
data NonEmptyList a = NEL a [a]
```

The functions `head`, `tail`, and others will become methods of a newly created `Listable` type class. Some functions can already fit in an existing type class (maps/folds/traversals/monads).

Why is such a type not part of the Haskell standard library?

Comment: How would you create an instance of that type?

Comment: You can find non-empty lists in the [`semigroups`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.16.0.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) package.

Comment: A more general answer is, that Haskell grew out of much more mundane means. It grew much much better over time. But changing the core libraries that all code relies on afterwards is a bad thing, no matter how much better the new stuff is. … **The current solution to this is that there are *alternate Prelude*s.** … Which, thanks to advanced compiler extensions, allow seemingly built-in syntax and literals in your code to be redefined to use better types. I highly recommend using those as early as possible, so you don’t have to unlearn certain things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is in base now since GHC 8.0: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html

---

The list of packages that define such a type is itself rather nonempty: there are at least six of them:

- [NonEmpty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmpty)
- [NonEmptyList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmptyList)
- [Cardinality](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cardinality)
- [non-empty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/non-empty)
- [semigroups](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups)
- [mono-traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable)

The Haskell Wiki has a whole [page](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Non-empty_list) about non-empty lists.

Your question: *why* are non-empty lists not in the base package is more difficult to answer. But the type is an instance of many useful classes from base (`Foldable`, `Zip`) so the machinery for using them is there already, and you need just a small number of instance definitions to use that.

Comment: can you provide an example and show how NonEmpty is used?

Answer (score 7):

The type actually exists.

You have to import

```
Data.List.NonEmpty
```

More info : http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.16.0.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html

Answer (score 6):

As of GHC 8.0.1, `base` now has a `NonEmpty` list type in `Data.List.NonEmpty`:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html